# org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am developing a web app with spring hibernate i got this error and i am stuck.

`2017 5:34:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/DevStockManagement] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at com.auhousing.daoImpl.AuthenticateDaoImpl.authenticate(AuthenticateDaoImpl.java:41)
    at com.auhousing.serviceImpl.AuthenticateServiceImpl.authenticate(AuthenticateServiceImpl.java:25)
    at com.auhousing.controller.LoginController.authenticate(LoginController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">



    <!-- 1.Define Controller Package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.auhousing.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.auhousing.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.auhousing.service" />


    <!-- 2.viewresolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="0"></property>
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/admin.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/branch.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/master.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/website.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

     <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stock_mgmt" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="masterDao" class="com.auhousing.daoImpl.MasterDaoImpl"/>


    <bean id="masterService" class="com.auhousing.serviceImpl.MasterServiceImpl"/>
         -->

         <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="aServiceImpl" class="com.auhousing.daoImpl.AuthenticateDaoImpl"/>
    <bean id="aDaoImpl" class="com.auhousing.serviceImpl.AuthenticateServiceImpl"/>

    <!-- <mvc:interceptors> <bean class="com.auhousing.Utils.SessionValidator"/> 
        </mvc:interceptors> -->
</beans>
```

this is config file dispatcher-servlet 
i am using spring 4 jar and hibernate 4 jars
[image][image]

Comment: looks like versions difference. Could you post your configs/dependencies?

Comment: i added the xml config in the after error log

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate.classic.Session  -  An extension of the Session API, including all deprecated methods from Hibernate2. This interface is provided to allow easier migration of existing applications. New code should use org.hibernate.Session.

Try to  change org.hibernate.classic.Session to org.hibernate.Session in your code

It looks like you are using an old Hibernate version for compilation and another more new version of Hibernate in a runtime.

Comment: i added the jar's screenshot at the end of question,

Comment: @Rakesh Did you try to change org.hibernate.classic.Session to org.hibernate.Session ?

Comment: from where i change this. i am new in hibernate & spring. So could you tell me

Comment: just find in your code org.hibernate.classic.Session and replace it with org.hibernate.Session

Comment: its the import . but in my code i didn;t find org.hibernate.classic.Session my code already have org.hibernate.session import & still showing same error

Comment: Thank You for Help. Error is solved. Its another bug that i fixed.Thank you for pointing main cause of error